# is this symbol  a kanji?

Tags: kanji

I see  as part of more than one kanji. I looked for its meaning in tables and dictionaries and I couldnt find anything. Does this symbol  have a meaning of its own?

Comment: U+242F1, [「入国管理局正字とその問題点」 (pdf)](http://kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~yasuoka/publications/2015-03-20.pdf)には「入国管理局正字に置き換えられない韓国の人名用漢字」として言及があります．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no universally agreed upon definition of what is or isn't a kanji, a question like `Is X a kanji` is ultimately opinion-based.

- 「」is a component simplified from「熏」by analogy (same method as 黑 > 黒) for [Shinjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai) [Jōyō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji) characters like「薫」.
- [Hyōgai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hy%C5%8Dgai_kanji) kanji are not officially simplified, so standalone「」does not have an official status in Japanese.

---

Outside of Japanese, there are two places where「」is recorded as a standalone character;

1. In one of the numerous [Dunhuang manuscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunhuang_manuscripts), and
2. In the Song Dynasty rime dictionary [[集韻]{しゅういん}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiyun). Quote from 集韻:

   [image]

   *Translation, quoting from the original [[說文解字]{せつもんかいじ}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) as this is what 集韻 refers to*:

   > 「[image]」、「」, [rimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie) as「許」as the onset and「云」as the final.《說文解字》definition: "Smoke from fire going upwards, compound character from「屮」and「黑」." The combination of「屮」and「黑」looks like smoke from fire going upwards (*ref. Seal Script version at the start*). In [clerical script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script), this is written as「」. [Vulgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_character#Orthodox_and_vulgar_variants) forms include「燻」, but this way of writing is wrong.

As can be seen in the 集韻 image, however, the standard style in this text was using characters that look like「黒」rather than「黑」, and these kinds of texts are where the numerous Chinese character variants throughout history are attested and recorded.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://qr.ae/TUTSn3) Quora answer for why it is extremely tricky trying to determine whether some character X is a Chinese character.

Answer (score 1):

I could find the following info [on this page](http://ksbookshelf.com/DW/Kanjirin/Kanjirin4q.html) (apparently from a dictionary called `漢字林` *Kanjirin*):

```
【】火4+9=総画数13 U+242F1 [クン/いぶ・す、いぶ・る、くゆ・らす、くす・べる、ふす・べる] 
【熏燻】［ノ丿十千田甲土里重、丶４灬］
◆物を燃やして煙を出す、（虫などを寄せ付けないように）煙を焚き込める
◆煙で食材を炙る、薫製にする
◆温暖なさま、心地よいさま
```